StateError (Bad state: Cannot use "ref" after the widget was disposed.)
Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Cannot use "ref" after the widget was disposed : flutter riverpodyour text
Hello I call a method that has some method in initstate. I click search button I got StateError (Bad state: Cannot use "ref" after the widget was disposed.) error.
I don't know how I can solve and actually I don't understand about that error. But my project work correct I test in vscode with all exception then I got error. I pasted my code here. Please help me..
My search button has that method below..

 void loadEksperList(String merkez) async {
    _eksperOzetListFuture = ref.read(mainEkspertizOzetProvider.notifier).getMainEkspertizOzetList(merkez);
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    _eksperOzetListFuture = loadData();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> loadData() async {
    await ref.read(userProvider.notifier).loadUser();
    await ref.read(memberShipProvider.notifier).getMembershipInfo();
    await ref.read(cityProvider.notifier).getCityList();
    await ref.read(merkezEkspertizProvider.notifier).getMerkezEkspertizList();
    _eksperOzetListFuture = ref.read(mainEkspertizOzetProvider.notifier).getMainEkspertizOzetList(""); // You can pass appropriate parameters here
  }
Future<void> getCityList() async {
    final db = await GoEksperDb().getDatabase();
    var data = await db.query('user_info');
    if (data.isNotEmpty) {
      var userData = data.first;
      if (userData.isNotEmpty) {
        try {
          var response = await Api().getFromApiWithoutResult(
            'Liste/IlGetir',
            userData['mobileId'] as String,
            null,
            userData['token'] as String,
          );
           if (response.success) {
            setStateData(response.data as Map<String, dynamic>);
          }
          else {
            setStateData({});
          }
        } catch (error) {
          setStateData({});
        }
      }
    }
  }

void setStateData(Map<String, Object?> cityData) {
    if (cityData.isNotEmpty) {
      List<CityResult> liste = [const CityResult(0, "İl")];
      for (var item in cityData.entries.toList()) {
        if (item.key.contains("values")) {
          for (var element in item.value as List) {
            liste.add(CityResult.fromJson(element));
          }
        }
      }
      state = liste;
    } else {
      state = [const CityResult(0, "İl")];
    }
  }
}


the order of super.initState(); is wrong. Put that as the first call inside of @override void initState() . That as the first thing, the second :  _eksperOzetListFuture = loadData(); needs to be covered by  if (mounted)  like this ->  if (mounted) {  _eksperOzetListFuture = loadData();  };

I applied but not work

Where ref comes from?

If ref is a global variable or comes from DI you have to cover every ref.read(...  with if(mounted) { ref.read(... your code....} because meanwhile it is waiting to read maybe your widget have changed its state where the old state is disposed

I used ConsumerSattefulWidget. ref comes from Consumer

if (mounted) {
await ref.read(userProvider.notifier).loadUser();
await ref.read(memberShipProvider.notifier).getMembershipInfo();
await ref.read(cityProvider.notifier).getCityList();
await ref.read(merkezEkspertizProvider.notifier).getMerkezEkspertizList();
_eksperOzetListFuture = ref
.read(mainEkspertizOzetProvider.notifier)
.getMainEkspertizOzetList("");

No, every await need to be covered. The dispose may be called between those awaits

you mean Future loadData() async {
if (mounted) {
await ref.read(userProvider.notifier).loadUser();
}
      if (mounted) {

await ref.read(memberShipProvider.notifier).getMembershipInfo();}
if (mounted) {
await ref.read(cityProvider.notifier).getCityList();
if (mounted) {
await ref.read(merkezEkspertizProvider.notifier).getMerkezEkspertizList();
_eksperOzetListFuture = ref
.read(mainEkspertizOzetProvider.notifier)
.getMainEkspertizOzetList("");
}
}

Yes in any call of ref.read in all methods. You doesn't know in which time your widget is disposed, may be between those calls.

Anyway there is a small piece of code that doesn't give a clear picture of your approach. May be you have chosen the wrong approach with all those await in a widget.

That's work thanks. Have to I check every place?

Especially in StatefulWidgets yes.  But in your shoes I'll change approach using some DI in some way.. Good luck :)

I don't use here DI but I want to use :)
